# Find $\lim\limits_{b\to a}\frac {1}{b-a}\ln\left[\frac{a(b-x)}{b(a-x)}\right]$ if $x$ is constant using l'Hospital's rule

Tags: calculus, limits

If $x$ is a constant what do I differentiate with respect to?
My best guess would be $b$. However, is this correct?
Also how do you differentiate that function with respect to $b?$
Do you have to use the product rule, chain rule and quotient rule?

Comment: It is correct. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes changing the notation makes it easier. Another way of verifying what you said is  replace $b$ by $x$, leave $a$ alone and replace $x$ by $c$. Then  differentiate wrt $x$ etc.

Answer (score 0):

hint: differentiating $\ln\left(\frac{a(b-x)}{b(a-x)}\right)$ with respect to $b$ we get
$$\frac{x}{b(b-x)}$$